# Specific Case of Overloading the = operator in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

How would I overload the = operator in a way that I could execute

```
int someInt;
MyClass instanceOfMyClass;
someInt = instanceOfMyClass;
```

Where MyClass contains an integer named number?

Comment: If you want it to be that transparent, how about a conversion operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't overload the `operator=` for the type `int`. What you are really looking for is the conversion operator `operator int()` for your `MyClass`. In your case, considering `x` to be the private member of your class:

```
operator int() { return x; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid doing this in most cases as it can be difficult to tell what exactly is happening. That said:

```
class MyClass {
 public:
  operator int() { return number; }

 private:
  int number;
};
```

This creates an (implicit) conversion operator for your class.

Comment: The only reason I'm doing it with this class is because the class is a random number generator. The integer of the class is the actual random number.

Comment: Why not use a normal method? `NextRandomNumber()` or something? It's possible doing this will obscure what the call does for no real benefit other than feeling clever.